# How Javascript Engines access/lookup property names?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

How Javascript Engines access/lookup property names? what kind of associative array (data structure or search/lookup algorithm) did they use? (for [`V8`](https://developers.google.com/v8/?csw=1), [`TraceMonkey`](https://wiki.mozilla.org/JavaScript:TraceMonkey), [`JSC`](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore), and [`Rhino`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino))

For example, in C++ there are `map` and `unordered_map` that uses (mostly) `RB-Tree` and `Hash Table`, but what for JavaScript `Object`/`{}` what kind of associative array did the use for each engine?

Or maybe more specific, how they store a `JSON` object internally?

Some answers that I've found, in `V8`, they use additional [Hash Table](http://www.slideshare.net/nwind/virtual-machine-and-javascript-engine) (slide 45)

Answer (score 1):

[JIT compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT_compilation) tracing techniques often make "hot" objects transformed into instances of hidden (and dynamically created) classes or structures, for which property access becomes as fast as field access in a C `struct`